# Show/hide toggler not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I have read the forums and tutorials but I am a beginner to jQuery and JS. I wanted to have multiple togglers on my page with show/hide content outside of my div and I am not able to achieve it. The closest I got is to have them, but all of them open and close at once.

I am trying to achieve the effect that if you click on "More content indicator", it dissapears and the hidden content would be showed and at the end of the content that was hidden and now is visible would be another Hide button.

See the code, please:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .wrapper {max-width: 1080px; margin: auto;}
    .hidden0 {display: none;}
    .showed0 {display: block;}
    #switcher0 {background: #fff; font-size: 50px; border-style: none; margin: auto; cursor: pointer;}
    .hidden1 {display: none;}
    .showed1 {display: block;}
    #switcher1 {background: #fff; font-size: 50px; border-style: none; margin: auto; cursor: pointer;}
    #hide0 {margin: 20px auto; display: block; cursor: pointer; background: #fff; font-size: 50px; border-style: none;}
    #hide1 {margin: 20px auto; display: block; cursor: pointer; background: #fff; font-size: 50px; border-style: none;}
    </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#toggler0").toggle(800);
            $('#switcher0').toggleClass('showed0 hidden0');
        });
    });

    $("#hide0").click(function(){
        $("#toggler0").hide(800);
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#toggler1").toggle(800);
            $('#switcher1').toggleClass('showed1 hidden1');
        });
    });

    $("#hide1").click(function(){
        $("#toggler1").hide(800);
    });

</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x600" alt="Placeholder">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies euismod erat ut lacinia. Phasellus ipsum orci, tristique eu bibendum et, sodales eu metus.</p>
                    <button id="switcher0" class="showed0">+<p style="font-size: 16px;">Číst více</p></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="toggler0" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="hide0">&uarr; <p  style="font-size: 16px;">Skrýt</p></button>
        </div>

            <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies euismod erat ut lacinia. Phasellus ipsum orci, tristique eu bibendum et, sodales eu metus.</p>
                    <button id="switcher1" class="showed1">+<p style="font-size: 16px;">Číst více</p></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x600" alt="Placeholder">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div id="toggler1" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Placeholder">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="hide1">&uarr; <p  style="font-size: 16px;">Skrýt</p></button>
        </div>

</div><!-- Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all in advance for help.

Comment: Not working, why? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npd2qsfm/1/ - I edited the script by the advice:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide0").click(function(){
    $("#toggler0").hide(800);
});
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#toggler0").toggle(800);
        $('#switcher0').toggleClass('showed0 hidden0');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#hide1").click(function(){
    $("#toggler1").hide(800);
});
        $("#toggler1").toggle(800);
        $('#switcher1').toggleClass('showed1 hidden1');
    });
});

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave each button two handlers, by twice calling `$("button").click(...)`, which I fixed.

I did some further cleanup to understand better what was going on, and I shrunk it to make it fit better on SO.

(Furthermore there is a lot of CSS present twice, I advise you to keep just half of it unless you really plan to make it two different styles.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Use $("#id") instead of $("button")
  $("#switcher0").click(function() {
    $("#toggler0").toggle(800);
    $('#switcher0').toggleClass('showed0 hidden0');
  });

  $("#hide0").click(function() {
    $("#toggler0").hide(800);
    $('#switcher0').toggleClass('showed0 hidden0');
  });

  // Use $("#id") instead of $("button")
  $("#switcher1").click(function() {
    $("#toggler1").toggle(800);
    $('#switcher1').toggleClass('showed1 hidden1');
  });

  $("#hide1").click(function() {
    $("#toggler1").hide(800);
    $('#switcher1').toggleClass('showed1 hidden1');
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hidden0 {
  display: none;
}

.showed0 {
  display: block;
}

#switcher0 {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden1 {
  display: none;
}

.showed1 {
  display: block;
}

#switcher1 {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hide0 {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-style: none;
}

#hide1 {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/340x260" alt="Placeholder">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies euismod erat ut lacinia. Phasellus ipsum orci, tristique eu bibendum et, sodales eu metus.</p>
        <button id="switcher0" class="showed0">+<p style="font-size: 16px;">Číst více</p></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="toggler0" style="display: none;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="hide0">&uarr; <p  style="font-size: 16px;">Skrýt</p></button>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies euismod erat ut lacinia. Phasellus ipsum orci, tristique eu bibendum et, sodales eu metus.</p>
        <button id="switcher1" class="showed1">+<p style="font-size: 16px;">Číst více</p></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/340x260" alt="Placeholder">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="toggler1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Placeholder">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="hide1">&uarr; <p  style="font-size: 16px;">Skrýt</p></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh, now I see it and thank you for your suggestion with CSS. I sure rewrite it to be more efficient.